# How can I make QT creator recognise different filename specifications for error / warning messages

Tags: qt, scons

I've been using qtcreator with an scons build, and for the life of me I can't get it to recognise the compile errors/warnings and put them in the build issues tab

The only difference I can see is that whereas the qmake output is something along the lines of

```
..\..\myfile.cpp:123:4 error xyz not declared in this scope
```

the scons output is along the lines of

```
project\subproject\myfile.cpp:123:4 error xyz not declared in this scope
```

as the scons build doesn't keep changing directory and builds from elsewhere.

Is there anything I can do to persuade QTCreator to look for the files in the right place, find them, and then add the appropriate line to the build issues tab,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have an answer (sort of).

I created a custom compiler which pointed to the studio compiler (not a clone) and changed my kit to use that.

Then I did a compile

Then I changed back to the microsoft visual studio compiler.

And now it works.

I have no idea why